# import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient in Groovy class

Tags: grails

I try to import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient in my groovy class. 
My groovy class is like this:

```
void getREST() {

    def r = new RESTClient(url) 
    def response = r.get(path:'test',headers:['Authorization': "auth"] )   
    println "RESPONSE"  
    println response.headers
    response.headers.each { it ->
        println it
    }

}
```

In my class, i import the RESTClient like this:

```
    import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
```

However, i got "unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.RESTClient" error. I am using NetBeans IDE 7.4.

I have already config the BuildConfig.groovy with the following code:

```
    compile ":rest:0.8"
```

and add the maven repo:

```
    mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org/"
```

But I still can't import the RESTClient. What should I do with that?

Comment: Did you `complie` the app after adding the plugin? Or refreshed dependencies?

Comment: Fix it.  just add one more: mavenRepo "http://grails.org/plugins".  This is interesting, this repo is not mention in the doc...

Comment: Nope.  What you really want is the [Grails Rest Client Builder][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24360224/30818

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it. just add one more repo to the BuildConfig:

```
mavenRepo "http://grails.org/plugins"
```

Comment: Grails will throw an error: `There was an error loading the BuildConfig: no protocol: grails.org/plugins`

Comment: @ivarPrudnikov that was a copy and paste from a comment, and in comments SO hides the `http://` at the front of links...