# RestClient Grails Import fails

Tags: grails, groovy

I can't import the `RESTClient` in my grails project. The message is:

```
Groovy:unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
```

In the `BuildConfig.groovy` I uncommented:

```
mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
```

and added:

```
compile ":rest-client-builder:2.0.0"
```

I'm using grails 2.3.8 and Windows 7.

Any ideas? The grails install-plugin does not work in this grails version.

Comment: Could You please paste the whole `BuildConfig.groovy`?

Comment: I have that plugin but not in the "compile" section. I have it as `build ":rest-client-builder:2.0.1"`

Comment: Its always worth trying `grails clean-all` when seeing errors like this...

Answer (score 3):

The `rest-client-builder` plugin doesn't provide a class called `groovyx.net.http.RESTClient`. I think you are getting confused with Groovy's REST client module:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/rest.html

The above module is not however recommended for us inside Grails applications and you are far better off with the `rest-client-builder` plugin, you just need to use the right API.

The docs for `rest-client-builder` are at

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rest-client-builder/

and

http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/rest-client/api/index.html