# Groovy:unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.RESTClient

Tags: rest, groovy

I am learning groovy for a scripting package called geoscript-groovy. I followed the groovy REST tutorial [here](http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-groovy.html) and tested the following code:

```
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient

def client = new RESTClient( 'http://www.acme.com/' )
def resp = client.get( path : 'products/3322' ) // ACME boomerang
```

However, I got an error at the `import` statement saying:

```
Groovy:unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
```

I searched around, and there are many questions and answers for this error message, e.g., [import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient in Groovy class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487301/import-groovyx-net-http-restclient-in-groovy-class) , and [RestClient Grails Import fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353035/restclient-grails-import-fails). However, they all for grails, which I don't use and am not very familiar with.

My question is

How should I fix this error if I have groovy only? (My version of groovy is installed under Ubuntu 12.04 with the following commands).

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:groovy-dev/groovy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install groovy
```

Thanks.

-- EDIT ---

I added @Grab statements as suggested, and put up a two-line `rest1.groovy` file as follows:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7')
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
```

`groovyConsole rest1.groovy` seems to run OK. But `groovysh < rest1.groovy` is still giving me an error (as shown below). I guess I need to have this run in a `groovysh`-like environment because the groovy script is called in the background as a web service. Without the `@Grab` line, the service generates an Exception. With the `@Grab` line, the service won't even register. Is there a more permanent way of including necessary dependencies for `groovyx.net.http.RESTClient` than a per script grab (e.g. an `apt-get` or manual copying of something)?

```
groovysh < rest1.groovy
Groovy Shell (1.8.6, JVM: 1.7.0_72)
Type 'help' or '\h' for help.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> @Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7')
groovy:001> import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandException:
Invalid import definition: 'import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient'; reason: startup failed:
script1413902882282760571375.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
```

Comment: Are you including http-builder in your classpath? 

Check out this example. http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/rest.html

Answer (score 17):

You probably just need the Grape line to properly make sure your Groovy script has the jar you need in the classpath.  Put this at the top of your script:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7' )
```

Note, I can't see the rest of your script, so there may be other modules you need to Grab too.
Check here for more possibilities:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/rest.html

EDIT

Well, glad it works part of the way now.  As far as groovysh goes, I don't know of a way to have groovysh dynamically get the dependent libraries, so what you really need to do is, as part of the script install, also put the jar you need in a directory (call it "lib" or some such), and then add the argument to your groovysh call:
groovysh -cp ./lib < script.groovy
from this: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Shell

The jar you want should be available via maven using the artifact specification from the @Grab line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It worked for `groovyConsole` but not for `groovysh`. Please see my EDIT.

Comment: Can you pls update the reference urls? codehaus.org is not resolving to IP