I am try to call a get API in Oracle CRM using Groovy scripting. Getting following error
Error: "unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.RESTClient"
I've attached a screenshot for reference
Here's the code I'm trying to run:
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient

// Define the REST API endpoint URL
def apiUrl = 'https://restapi.echo.com/v2/Shipments/55493611'

// Define your authentication credentials
def username = 'E178387'
def password = 'a9eaeb31-6f33-4e62-b0b7-a6ea446438fb'

// Create a REST client
def restClient = new RESTClient(apiUrl)

// Set authentication headers
restClient.headers['Authorization'] = "Basic " + "${username}:${password}".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()

// Make a GET request
def response = restClient.get()

// Check the response status code
if (response.status == 200) {
    // Parse the JSON response
    def jsonResponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response.data)
    // Process the JSON data
    println "Response: $jsonResponse"
} else {
    println "Error: ${response.status} - ${response.statusText}"
}


this might be a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475643/groovyunable-to-resolve-class-groovyx-net-http-restclient

Does this answer your question? Groovy:unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.RESTClient

I do not have Groovy installed in system. I'm trying it in Oracle CRM web page. Is it possible without having Groovy installed?
